# Converting integer in reverse order to gererate IP in reverse order

Tags: go, ip-address, bitwise-operators

I wanted to generate IP in reverse order.

Functionality which generate IP address is as follow:

```
val := 1<<(32-prefixLen) // let take prefixLen as 24
IP4(val) = IP4(256) = 0.0.1.0
```

I wanted the IP in reverse order i.e., `0.1.0.0`, so convert the `val` in reverse order bytes and send it to `IP4()` function.

Functionality which I have tried resulted in integer overflow:

```
temp1:=byte(val*0xff<<24)    
temp2:=byte(val*0xff00<<16)   
temp3:=byte(val*0xff0000<<8)
temp4:=byte(val*0xff000000)  
valReverse := uint32(temp4)|uint32(temp3)|uint32(temp2)|uint32(temp1)
IP4(valReverse)=0.1.0.0 //expected
```

Comment: Did you want to reverse the order of the bytes of a IPv4? Or the bit order of the bytes? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

### Reversing bytes

First, you have to use `uint32` type instead of `byte` as a `byte` value only has 8 bits (bit positions above 8 don't exist).

Next, you have to use bitwise AND which is `&` and not the multiplication `*`.

Third, the shift values are incorrect. See this working example:

```
prefixLen := uint32(24)

var val uint32
val = 1 << (32 - prefixLen)
fmt.Printf("%08x\n", val)

temp1 := uint32(val & 0xff << 24)
temp2 := uint32(val & 0xff00 << 8)
temp3 := uint32(val & 0xff0000 >> 8)
temp4 := uint32(val & 0xff000000 >> 24)
valReverse := uint32(temp4) | uint32(temp3) | uint32(temp2) | uint32(temp1)

fmt.Printf("%08x\n", valReverse)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7U9QmcZDkN)):

```
00000100
00010000
```

But personally I would just use the [`net.IP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP) type which models an IP address with a byte slice, and using that you can simply reverse the bytes with a slice-reversing algorithm.

This is how it would look like:

```
ip := net.IPv4(0, 0, 1, 0).To4()
fmt.Println(ip)

// Reverse:
for i, j := 0, len(ip)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
    ip[i], ip[j] = ip[j], ip[i]
}
fmt.Println(ip)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GBe4PoQL5o)):

```
0.0.1.0
0.1.0.0
```

Note: if you have the IP as a value of `uint32`, you can still use the `net.IP` type, creating the `net.IP` value like this:

```
ip := net.IPv4(byte(val>>24), byte(val>>16), byte(val>>8), byte(val)).To4()
```

### Reversing bits

If you want to reverse bits, you have to do that bit-by-bit. One possible solution is this:

```
prefixLen := uint32(24)

var val uint32
val = 1 << (32 - prefixLen)
fmt.Printf("%08x\n", val)

var valReverse uint32
for i := 0; i < 32; i, val = i+1, val>>1 {
    valReverse = valReverse<<1 | val&0x01
}
fmt.Printf("%08x\n", valReverse)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GzUDU2aDzo)):

```
00000100
00800000
```

An alternative, maybe more complex way to reverse the bits:

```
var valReverse uint32
for mask1, mask2 := uint32(0x01), uint32(0x80000000); mask2 != 0; mask1, mask2 = mask1<<1, mask2>>1 {
    if val&mask1 != 0 {
        valReverse |= mask2
    }
}
```

Output is the same, try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mPmB6Ja5lU).

Comment: thanks for the answer @icza.. actually my input is integer where the net.IPv4 takes octacts as input. Is their any way to get the octacts from integer. or gererate IPs in reverse order. As I can see my solution does not work well if prefixLength changes.

Comment: @ravi_ss See edited answer. I also showed a way to reverse bits. Also if you have the IP as a value of `uint32`, you can still use the `net.IP` type by creating a value of it like this: `ip := net.IPv4(byte(val>>24), byte(val>>16), byte(val>>8), byte(val)).To4()`

Comment: Can please check this I needed solution to this issue https://play.golang.org/p/uz90ZVu47h